# which API should i use to check inapp purchase in Java server side code?

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have developed android Apps which provide services for paying users, using Google Play's in-app purchase features. I want to verify *on the server* that the user who is requesting services has paid. My server-side code is written in Java. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

This library from Google should get you this functionality:

https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client